# Unable to identify the webelement when the mouse hovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium-webdriver, primefaces

I have tried many ways to identify this WebElement and could not succeed.
I want to click on the button and when I do not hover the mouse on the button then this is the html code:

```
<button name="j_idk32"
class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" 
id="j_idk32"
role="button"
aria-disabled="false"
style="font-size: 10pt;"
onclick='PrimeFaces.ab({s:"j_idk32"});return false;' type="submit">
<span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Enter Application</span></button>
```

When I hover the mouse on the button then below is the html code:

```
<button name="j_idk32" 
class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-focus" 
id="j_idk32" 
role="button" 
aria-disabled="false" 
style="font-size: 10pt;" 
onclick='PrimeFaces.ab{s:"j_idk32"});return false;' type="submit">
<span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Enter Application</span></button>
```

There is an extra "class" attribute "ui-state-focus" in the second version.

Comment: what is the actual problem? I cannot imagine the `ui-state-focus` class being present or not makes a big difference in you succeding in selecting the webelement or not. Off-topic: Ask the devs to assign implicit id's to buttons and you will be able to select it based on id.

Comment: Add the css or xpath or the selector you are using? What is the code you are using for hover and click?

Comment: This is the code that I have used.   ~//new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("C span.ui-button-text ui-c"))).click();~   But still it is not identifying the webelement.  I have also used  ~WebElement btnReg = driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt42"));
   WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(btnReg));
   Actions action = null;
 action.moveToElement(btnReg).build().perform();
   action.click(btnReg).perform();~

Comment: I have also tried xpath - ~driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only']")).click(); ~   But still not able to locate the webelement.